# jsPlumb or jQuery Connections, used on collapsible content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I'm trying to add connecting lines from a chat bubble to two child bubbles that are collapsible. Example in the link. I am not very experienced with JS, I'm learning as I try to create this project.

I've tried using jQuery Connections, and am currently reading the documentation for jsPlumb. Connections works on its own when I try it, but when I try to use it on collapsible content, it doesn't work. I've tried specifying the connection source as the ".active" version of the button/word bubble, so I would think the connections would pop up when clicked:

```js
/* jQuery connections */
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"</script>
        <script src="jquery.connections.js"></script>
        <script>
          jQuery.noConflict();
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("button.active").connections("div.li1");
          });
        </script>
        
/* Collapsible JavaScript */
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
      connection {
        z-index: -1;
        border: 3px solid red;
        border-radius: 7em;
        color: black;
      }
      
      
      .buttona { 
        color: #1D163E; 
        background: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: sans-serif, "SEGOE-UI";
        text-align: left; 
        border-radius: 43px;
        border: 2px solid #1D163E;
        padding: 20px;
        max-width: 400px;
        display: block;
      }

      /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
      .active, .buttona:hover {
        border: 2px solid #7FFF00;
      }

      /* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
      .messagera {
        color: #1D163E; 
        background: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: sans-serif, "SEGOE-UI";
        text-align: left; 
        border-radius: 43px;
        padding: 20px;
        max-width: 400px;
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-left: 40px;
      }
      /* Collapsible content for lists */

      p {
        color: #1D163E; 
        background: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: sans-serif, "SEGOE-UI";
        text-align: left; 
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 43px;
        border: 2px solid #1D163E;
        max-width: 150px;
        padding: 20px;
        width:50%; 
        float:left;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      img {
        width: 7%;
      }
```

```html
   
      <button type="button" class="buttona">
not having read the links yet, my immediate comments- as i see it there are two main things that are sus about “veganism - and you touched on both:
      </button>
      <div class="messagera">
        <p class="li1"><img src="1.jpg">
the relationship between veganism and expensive or otherwise 
exclusive “vegan foods” sold in stores</p>
      <p class="li2" style="width: 100%; float: right;"><img src="2a.jpg">
The stigma on veganism is a cultural reaction to
what was once perceived as a threat to society.
now that stigma is a meme used by people 
entrenched in vegan culture to pose as
oppressed heroic revolutionaries </p>
      </div>
    <form action="/">
        <input type="text" name="message" />
        <input class="message" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

[Example of objective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWRyv.png)

Comment: Your Snippet is throwing errors. Would be useful to fix those.

Comment: I think you're trying to pull in jquery-connections, but your URL is a local one. You need to reference a CDN.

Comment: It may be because I took snippets of the code. I'm using repl.it as an IDE, so I uploaded the libraries on there and am referencing them directly. Here's the repl if it helps/is accessible https://repl.it/@cvnloveit/CVN-chat-demo